# Swap key and value in a map in fsharp

Tags: dictionary, f#, functional-programming, swap

How to create a new map that is similar to the original one, but with swapped keys and values in Fsharp? 
For example, I have this

```
let map1 =
[("A", "1"); ("B", "2"); ("C", "3");]
|> Map.ofList
```

and want to get this:

```
let map2 =
[("1", "A"); ("2", "B"); ("3", "C");]
|> Map.ofList
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What particular part are you stuck on - show an attempt?

Comment: @John Palmer Is there any reason to show code that doesn't work?

Comment: Of course - it gives us an idea of how best to help you.  For example - there is a pretty obvious solution with ordinary performance - maybe that is OK for your situation.  maybe your solution just has a tiny error that can be fixed etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you will approach this decision:

```
let map1 = Map.ofList [("A", "1"); ("B", "2"); ("C", "3")]

map1 |> printfn "%A"

let rev map: Map<string,string> = 
      Map.fold (fun m key value -> m.Add(value,key)) Map.empty map

rev map1 |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
map [("A", "1"); ("B", "2"); ("C", "3")]
map [("1", "A"); ("2", "B"); ("3", "C")]
```

Link: http://ideone.com/cfN2yH

Comment: Note you can make it type `Map<'a,'b>` if you don't want to restrict to strings.

Comment: @Dax Fohl, Thank you. So much better

Answer (score 6):

You could convert it to a list and back, calling a function to swap in the middle.

```
let swap (x, y) = y, x
let swapAll tuples = List.map swap tuples
let invert map = map |> Map.toList |> swapAll |> Map.ofList
```

This method somewhat highlights what's nice about functional programming--you can build up complex behavior just by combining small building blocks.